# How do you create multiple substrings in C?

Tags: c

So, I am reading a line from a text file, and then I am trying to parse it into tokens at every recurrence of “;” or” &”, and keep every token within my linked list of strucs.

I have tried strtok(), but it does not work for my case, since I have to keep track of my ";" or "&".

For example:

Input line:

”one     &           two; three&       four&  five;”

NOTE:there are could be multiple spaces between &/; and the next string

Once parsing has been completed I should get a list of structs that will look like this:

```
struct node1{char *token='one'; char *dim='&'}
struct node2{char *token='two'; char *dim=';'}
struct node3{char *token='three'; char *dim='&'}
struct node4{char *token='four'; char *dim='&'}
struct node5{char *token='five'; char *dim=';'}
```

I just need help with parsing the input.

Comment: The `strcspn` and `strspn` functions may be useful.

Comment: There is a difference between `"one"` and `';'`. `'one'` is legal, but should never be used because it does not have a defined meaning. `';'` is a semicolon *character* (**not** a string) and therefore a `char`, not a `char*`. I'm sure yourC textbook explains this in detail.

Comment: Please show some effort what you tried and why it didn't work: Tell us which functions of the string library you considered and why their result is wrong for you.